# How do I pass a return value from one method to another?

Tags: methods, parameters, return

I need to pass a return value from windCorrectionAngle method to groundSpeed method and place it at the very end of the expression ("windCorAng"). This is the only part that doesn't work for me. From what I learned it is not something that Java can do easily because it can't see the return from other methods. Would love to learn how to do that and what is a proper way of doing it. I have a simple print line to get the result of grSpd.

```
public double windCorrectionAngle()
{
double windCorAng = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin 
( vw * Math.sin( Math.toRadians (w-d) ) / va) ); 
return windCorAng;
}

public double groundSpeed()
{
double grSpd = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(va,2) + Math.pow(vw,2) - 2 * va * vw * 
Math.cos(Math.toRadians(d - w - windCorAng))); 
return grSpd;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the return value of a function in an expression, just place a function call there, i. e.:

```
public double groundSpeed()
{
    return Math.sqrt( Math.pow(va, 2) + Math.pow(vw, 2)
                    - 2 * va * vw * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(d - w - windCorrectionAngle()))
                    ); 
}
```